# Typescript+webpack: typescript emmited no output for index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) to setup typescript+webpack (no react) with success. 
It all works great until I add index.d.ts file my components folder, which I use to export all my modules, like:

```
export * from "./MyClass1";
export * from "./MyClass2";
export * from "./MyClass2";
```

Then I import it:

```
import * as MyLib from "./components";
```

Code hinting and everything works fine in sublime editor.

Initially, when I run it, I've got:

**Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components**

So I added d.ts to extensions in webpack.config.js:

```
 resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".d.ts"]
    },
```

Now, when I run webpack, I get this error:

**Typescript emitted no output for [...]\index.d.ts**

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? Also, try setting the `compilerOptions.moduleResolution = "node"` in tsconfig, and retry the step where it wasn't finding ./components

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link - updated question. I tried adding "moduleResolution":"node" to tsconfig, but nothing changed, both with d.ts added to extensions and not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> index.d.ts

This is a *declaration file*. A declaration file has no javascript emit.

## Fix

Make sure that the `.d.ts` file is not a part of the required emit by excluding it from webpack e.g. by redirecting it to [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader)

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/
},
{
    test: /\.d\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ignore-loader'
},
```

Comment: This works fine, except that now, if I import it like: import * as MyLib from "./components"; it shows: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './components'. Only if I import it like import {MyClass} from "./components" it works fine. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I asked another question regarding this other error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251505/typescript-index-d-ts-and-webpack-module-not-found-error

Comment: Please explain more. As-is, N. Kudryavtsev's answer was more helpful, although feeling a little like circumventing the problem. I checked your resource with no clarity, and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) says `.d.ts` are by default included, so I don't know what you mean by adding it to "compilation context".

Comment: Came across this answer and it's not really clear. Any elaboration?

Answer (score 24):

In this particular question the content of `index.d.ts` was not a definition but a module and should have been moved into `index.ts` file.
I've also ran into error "typescript emmited no output for index.d.ts" but with valid declaration files.

It seems `ts-loader` tries to add `.d.ts` files to final bundle but finds nothing to add since they contain only declarations needed for type-checking during build.

Working solution for me is not to pass `.d.ts` files to `ts-loader` but to some loader that does nothing, e. g. [ignore-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-loader). Corresponding rules in my `webpack.config.js` are:

```
{
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/
},
{
    test: /\.d\.ts$/,
    loader: 'ignore-loader'
},
```

`ts-loader` can be configured slightly differently if you use ES2018, where negative lookbehind for regular expressions was added:

```
{
    test: /(?<!\.d)\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
},
//same ignore-loader config here
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well. Thanks. 
However, the ts-loader should handle this for itself.
It does not make sense, that one has to explicitly send d.ts file to dev null.

Comment: Minor contribution: `exclude: ["/node_modules/", /\.d\.ts$/iu]` as an array also works and is slightly better to read.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration files should be imported using the `type` keyword.

`import type * as MyLib from "./components"`