# Typescript, index.d.ts and webpack: Module not found error

Tags: typescript

I created Typescript project with webpack, following [this tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).
As I have a lot of modules, I added index.d.ts to my src/components folder where I export all my modules:

```
export {Module1} from "./Module1";
export {Module2} from "./Module2";
export {Module3} from "./Module3";
```

I added index.d.ts to tsconfig.json files:

```
"files": [
    "./src/components/index.d.ts"
]
```

Then, in index.tsx, which is in src folder, I import:

```
import * as MyModule from "./components/";
```

Code hinting works fine, so I suppose all paths are OK. 
However when I run webpack, I get this error:

**Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './components'**

As I understand, webpack doesn't find this index.d.ts file. I tried adding d.ts to webpack.config.js extensions, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231645/typescriptwebpack-typescript-emmited-no-output-for-index-d-ts), but then I've got a different error message. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

For me, I ended up changing it from `'./types'` to `'./types.d'`.

So a type import would look something like,

```
import {
    TSomeType,
    ISomeInterface,
    ESomeEnum
} from 'src/types/components/SomeComponent/types.d'
```

instead of,

```
import {
    TSomeType,
    ISomeInterface,
    ESomeEnum
} from 'src/types/components/SomeComponent/types'
```

Taken from [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4874#issuecomment-287349128) comment:

> I can confirm this issue, @Draccoz @filipesilva .

> It does not happen when you change the filename from .d.ts to .ts.
> It also does not happen when you change your import from import { Something } from 'yourlib'; to import { Something } from 'yourlib.d';

> I just moved a working project from a webpack-starter seed (TypeScript/Angular) to CLI and got this error, so I assume it has something to do with the generated CLI project.

> I'm using @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2

---

I think that it's also worth to note that tsx files work just fine. I had to change `types` to `types.d` only for ts files.

Answer (score 3):

Came up with a solution to use index.ts for all exports instead of index.d.ts.

Answer (score 1):

Found a very simple solution that works like a charm:

Just add type after `import`.

```
import type { ISomeInterface } from 'src/types/components/SomeComponent/types'
```