# webpack can't resolve d.ts files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

guys!

I tried to import d.ts files, but encountered the following error:
`Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`

I guess, it's kind of trouble with webpack loaders, so webpack can't handle d.ts files.

[webpack-modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71866.jpg)

```
"webpack": "^5.27.2",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
"webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
```

error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/extypes/typings/index.d.ts 3:0-27
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './telegram' in 'D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings'
resolve './telegram' in 'D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings'
  using description file: D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\package.json (relative path: 
./typings)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\package.json (relative path: ./typings/telegram)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings\telegram doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings\telegram.tsx doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings\telegram.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings\telegram.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        D:\devprojects\node\changex\crm\node_modules\extypes\typings\telegram doesn't exist
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Why would you load `d.ts` files with webpack? They are just type definitions. Webpack's `ts-loader` doesn't check types. It doesn't need `d.ts`.

Comment: so how should I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of you `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` files?

Comment: @desrev3r, any update on how you got past this issue? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @ONMNZ, nah, dude. do you?

Comment: Maybe this could help; this did not work `export * from './types/auth'`  but adding the d to have this `export * from './types/auth.d' ` worked. I found it on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251505/typescript-index-d-ts-and-webpack-module-not-found-error

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in a nuxt project and was able to resolve it by adding `"declaration": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file.
You can also check the npm docs for insight about declaration files
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#declaration-files-dts

also this might be specific to me but webpack was showing this warning because I was wrongly requiring a dynamic image file e.g `<img :src="require('~/${dynamic}')">`

so perhaps that might be important to check too