# Typescript declaration files .d.ts not found / is not a module

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have moved purely type definitions into a separate file, as `index.d.ts`.

However, if I run Webpack, compilation fails because `\index \index.ts \index.tsx...` does not exist. These correspond to my webpack config, on `resolve: { extensions: [] }`

If I add `.d.ts` to the extensions array however, the error becomes that file is not a module.

How should I configure this properly, without turning the `.d.ts` into a plain `.ts` file?

P.S. Using `ts-loader`

Comment: is this helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251505/typescript-index-d-ts-and-webpack-module-not-found-error

Comment: @nima No, as the solution is either not use `.d.ts` and use plain `.ts`, or to modify the import as from `index.d` instead. VSCode when auto adding imports will use `index` instead of `index.d`, so I wouldn't want to manually write this every time - doesn't feel like that's the design way

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: No, haven't got anything other than just use .ts for now. Will post an answer when I've looked into it properly

Comment: Any update on this? I'm facing a similar issue: in the `.d.ts` file, when I import something from other file, the `.d.ts` file works without any configuration; when no import, ts complains that the file "is not a module"

Comment: Do you have enums in your .d.ts ?

Comment: .d.ts cannot has enums